# VMWare ESX server does not recognize RAID 10 datastore

Tags: vmware-esx

we have a RAID 10 datastore (4x SAS) on an IBM x3650M2 server but our VMWare ESX 4.xx server does not see this datastore.

Does anybody knows whats wrong there?

Answer (score 1):

Is the array controller on the HCL?  The only [SAS array I see supported](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?action=search&deviceCategory=san&productId=1&advancedORbasic=advanced&maxDisplayRows=50&key=&release%5B%5D=13&datePosted=-1&partnerId%5B%5D=-1&arrayTypeId%5B%5D=4&isSVA=0&rorre=0) from IBM for esx 4 is model 1820N00. If it's built in servraid make sure [its one of these](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?action=search&deviceCategory=io&productId=1&advancedORbasic=advanced&maxDisplayRows=50&key=ibm&datePosted=-1&partnerId%5B%5D=-1&ioTypeId%5B%5D=7&manufacturer%5B%5D=-1&vid=&did=&svid=&ssid=&rorre=0) Also note:

"SAS 2.0 controllers are supported only with VMware ESX/ESXi 4.0u1 and newer releases"

Answer (score 0):

It´s a ServeRaid M5014 SAS/SATA Controller. The ESX regognizes a RAID 5 but not RAID 10.

I can´t find ESX4.0U1. Where is it downloadable?

Comment: http://downloads.vmware.com/d/info/datacenter_downloads/vmware_vsphere_4/4

Comment: Here is is on the HCL; http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?action=search&deviceCategory=io&productId=1&advancedORbasic=advanced&maxDisplayRows=50&key=M5014&datePosted=-1&partnerId%5B%5D=-1&manufacturer%5B%5D=-1&vid=&did=&svid=&ssid=&rorre=0

Comment: Thank you for the link. Why isn´t the update shown in the vSphere Host Update Utility?

Comment: I don´t know why but now I see the disk in the LUN configuration.

Comment: Don't know, I use VCUM not the HUU.

Comment: What is VCUM, is it free?